# Subset data frame based on date (month) using variables

Tags: r, variables, subset

I have a very large data frame which I would like to subset into months, based on a date column of the type `%Y-%m%-%d`. It looks like this:

```
>head(df)

       TID ItemID       Date
1 89522728  17265 2017-12-29
2 89522728  13228 2017-12-29
3 89522712  20894 2017-12-29
4 89522712  31013 2017-12-29
5 89522704  11097 2017-12-29
6 89522704  27290 2017-12-29
```

I have tried a couple of things without a solution (e.g. a loop and other not so elegant ways), and now I have resorted with the following thing, which works:

```
jan <- subset(df, format.Date(Date, "%m")=="01")
feb <- subset(df, format.Date(Date, "%m")=="02")
mar <- subset(df, format.Date(Date, "%m")=="03")
.
.
.
dec <- subset(df, format.Date(Date, "%m")=="12")
```

However, there must be some other nice elegang solution, where I can be free of writing the same code over and over again? E.g. like `c <- c("jan", "feb", ... "dec")` and then use that with a `d <- seq(1,12,by=1)` and combine it with the `subset` part? Am I totally wrong, or is there a neat and elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it is better to create a list of data frames rather than creating free data frames in the global environment.  `L$Jan`, `L$Feb`, etc. or `L[[1]]`, `L[[2]]`, etc. can then be used to refer to any particular month's data frame.

```
L <- split(DF, format(DF$Date, "%m"))
names(L) <- month.abb[as.numeric(names(L))]
```

It would be possible to copy these to the global environment although, as mentioned, it is not recommended:

```
list2env(L, .GlobalEnv)
```